# How to start multiple spark workers on one machine in Spark 2.4?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to setup a small spark cluster on my local Mac machine, one master and two or more workers. In [Spark 2.0.0 doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/spark-standalone.html) there is a property `SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES` which states

> Number of worker instances to run on each machine (default: 1). You
> can make this more than 1 if you have very large machines and
> would like multiple Spark worker processes. If you do set this, make
> sure to also set `SPARK_WORKER_CORES` explicitly to limit the cores per
> worker, or else each worker will try to use all the cores.

However, this same property is missing from [Spark 2.4](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/spark-standalone.html)

Answer (score 2):

The link [Spark 2.0.0 doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/spark-standalone.html) you provided is pointing to `2.0.0-preview` and not to [`2.0.0`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/spark-standalone.html) in which the property is also missing.

It was removed from the documentation as per this Jira issue [SPARK-15781](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15781) and the corresponding [Github PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/13533):

> Like `SPARK_JAVA_OPTS` and `SPARK_CLASSPATH`, we will remove the document
> for `SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES` to discourage user not to use them. If they
> are actually used, SparkConf will show a warning message as before.

You can also read this from the migration guide [Upgrading from Core 2.4 to 3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/core-migration-guide.html):

> `SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES` is deprecated in Standalone mode. It’s
> recommended to launch multiple executors in one worker and launch one
> worker per node instead of launching multiple workers per node and
> launching one executor per worker.

And will be removed in future versions : [Remove multiple workers on the same host support from Standalone backend](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30978)

I think its main purpose was for testing spark on laptops but I wasn't able to find a doc that confirms this, as in practice, it makes no sense to have multiple workers per node.

Comment: "as in practice, it makes no sense to have multiple workers per node." Why?

Comment: @Adelin Because of shared host resources between the 2+ workers on that same node. There'll be conflicts when each one tries to allocate resource to executors. And there is no use case for this (at least from my own experience :) )